# How to lock users using Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, authorization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to add a subscription type functionality in my application for the account holder users such that with few failed login attempts they will not be able to access their account. Note: I don't want to delete their account from the database. I've already installed `devise-2.1.2` in my application. Do any body have any idea how can it be done? I am newbie to `Ruby on rails` so it will be very helpful to me if you please explain the steps.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Devise have a buil-in solution with the `:lockable` option check in the [Devise Lockable Documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Lockable)

You have to set the `lock_strategy` set to `:failed_attempts.`

*Step 1*
Set your config/initializers/devise.rb to use:

```
# Defines which strategy will be used to lock an account.
config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

# Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
config.unlock_keys = [ :time ]

# Defines which strategy will be used to unlock an account.
# :time  = Re-enables login after a certain amount of time (see :unlock_in below)
config.unlock_strategy = :time

# Number of authentication tries before locking an account if lock_strategy
# is failed attempts.
config.maximum_attempts = 3

# Time interval to unlock the account if :time is enabled as unlock_strategy.
config.unlock_in = 2.hours
```

*Step 2*
Your should add the lockable to you Model as this:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, 
         :lockable
```

*Step 3*
Generate the migrations to make devise work

```
class AddLockableToExamples < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :examples, :failed_attempts, :integer, default: 0
    add_column :examples, :unlock_token, :string
    add_column :examples, :locked_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

Regards!!

Comment: I want to clear this thing in my mind that `failed attempts` are only for that situation if any user has tried signing up for certain number of times.

Comment: Also the documentation says that a time type strategy can be used for locking up an account. So i want to give subscription to a user for few months after then as soon as the subscription over, he ll not be able to use his account. Is this possible?

Comment: It locks when user attempt x times to signing IN and you may set the unlock_strategy to time. That is what you need!

Comment: This should be used only for sign in blocks, the other thing is part of the logic of your applicaiton, you should implement it.

Comment: I added a tep by step to help you, probably this is what you need!

Comment: Done. But that subscription thing.. i m not getting how to do it.?

Comment: Greate answer you have posted, this is very helpful for me. :)

Comment: should add index ? 
`add_column :examples, :unlock_token, :string, index: true`