# Lockable is not working in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have implemented Devise on two user accounts Admin and Customer. Register sign_in functions are working fine. I'm trying to implement lockable on an admin account. I'm using Devise 3.2.4.

After entering wrong credentials for specific time the account is still active and it doesn't record failed_attempts.

I have followed this guide [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184514/how-to-lock-users-using-devise).

My devise.rb:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.secret_key = 'XXXXX_the_secret_key_XXXXXXX'

  config.mailer_sender = 'mymail@domain.com'

  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  # config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]

  # config.request_keys = []

  config.case_insensitive_keys = [ :email ]

  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [ :email ]

  # config.params_authenticatable = true

  # config.http_authenticatable = false

  # config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = true

  # config.http_authentication_realm = 'Application'

  # config.paranoid = true

  # passing :skip => :sessions to `devise_for` in your config/routes.rb
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]

  # config.clean_up_csrf_token_on_authentication = true

  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 10

  # config.pepper = '38635688e9d775b28e8da07b695dfced7b3bd4899c0a9a2a0f9b5ed5a8113e79864f76039166f827ef0134452fc0080f279adc4d1724362e079d0af3361edaf5'

  # config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 2.days

  # config.confirm_within = 3.days

  config.reconfirmable = true

  # config.confirmation_keys = [ :email ]

  # config.remember_for = 2.weeks

  # config.extend_remember_period = false

  # config.rememberable_options = {}

  # Range for password length.
  config.password_length = 8..128

  # config.email_regexp = /\A[^@]+@[^@]+\z/

  # config.timeout_in = 30.minutes

  # config.expire_auth_token_on_timeout = false

  # :failed_attempts = Locks an account after a number of failed attempts to sign in.
  # :none            = No lock strategy. You should handle locking by yourself.
  config.lock_strategy = :failed_attempts

  # Defines which key will be used when locking and unlocking an account
  config.unlock_keys = [ :email ]
  # config.unlock_keys = [ :time ]

  config.unlock_strategy = :both
  # config.unlock_strategy = :time

  config.maximum_attempts = 3

  config.unlock_in = 2.hour

  # config.last_attempt_warning = false

  config.reset_password_within = 24.hours

  # config.encryptor = :sha512

  config.sign_out_via = :delete

end
```

My Admin model:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable
end
```

My migration to add lockable on admin:

```
class AddLockableToAdmin < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :admins, :failed_attempts, :integer, default: 0
    add_column :admins, :unlock_token, :string
    add_column :admins, :locked_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

My routes.rb:

```
devise_for :admins
```

Comment: After 3 failed attempts to login, check in the `rails console` whether or not `failed_attempts` count for that particular `Admin` user is set. Please share the results in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**STEP 1: verify that devise is correctly installed**

**1-** You are missing `null: false` in the `failed_attempts` field of the migration.

`add_column :admins, :failed_attempts, :integer, default: 0, null: false`

Fix it and rerun your migration

**2-** Update all existing records in your console:

`Admin.update_all failed_attempts: 0`

**3-** Shutdown your server, console and anything else that uses or preload your application (spring, zeus etc...)

**4-** in your rails console, verify that devise is correctly installed

`Admin.new.respond_to? :failed_attempts` should return true

**5-** Still in your console, verify that `Admin` can be locked manually:

`Admin.first.lock_access!`

You should see the SQL updating `locked_at` and `unlock_token` fields of your records

**6-** Start your server and try again entering a wrong password (using another user for which you locked manually off course), see if the value of `failed_attempts` changes

*=> result: All work, but logging-in with wrong credential does not increment `failed_attempts`*

---

**STEP2: Verify where devise fails**

Brute-force debugging

I don't know if you have a debugger, so we are going to edit temporarily the method responsible of incrementing `failed_attempts`, and see where it stops. Open in devise gem the file "lib/devise/models/lockable.rb" and edit it like this:

```
def valid_for_authentication?
  puts 'mark 1'
  return super unless persisted? && lock_strategy_enabled?(:failed_attempts)
  puts 'mark 2'

  # Unlock the user if the lock is expired, no matter
  # if the user can login or not (wrong password, etc)
  unlock_access! if lock_expired?

  if super && !access_locked?
    puts 'mark 3 (you should not see me)'
    true
  else
    puts 'mark 4 (you are supposed to see me)'
    self.failed_attempts ||= 0
    self.failed_attempts += 1
    if attempts_exceeded?
      puts 'mark 5 (you should not see me)'
      lock_access! unless access_locked?
    else
      puts 'mark 6 (you are supposed to see me)'
      save(validate: false)
    end
    false
  end
end
```

As you can see I added "marks" to see where the execution pass. Note that depending on your version of devise, the content of the method may be slightly different, you just need to add the "marks".

Restart your server, try one log-in with incorrect credential, and look at your console to see which marks are displayed.

After our test you can revert this file to remove the marks

*=> Result: None of the mark is displayed in console during a log-in with wrong credential*

Execute in console `Admin.first.valid_for_authentication?`

*=> Result: The marks 1, 2, 4, 6 are displayed and the `failed_attempts` is incremented in database*

---

**SOLUTION** (Still to be confirmed)

The form used for authentication have an `action` value which is not redirecting to the devise controller. It seems that you are using `api_console` that is generating the form for authentication.

Comment: (I bet you have a validation problem, we'll see after your answer)

Comment: Solved: i was using devise_token_auth along with devsie and support for lockable was recently added to devise_token_auth in this PR: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/pull/669

Answer (score 4):

After following the advice of Benj, I failed to get it to work. When debugging *lib/devise/models/lockable.rb* the code entered the `if super && !access_locked?` condition.

It turns out my issue was in the sign-in procedure, where I used the `valid_for_authentication?` function incorrectly. I.e. I did a check similar to this:

```
if user.valid_for_authentication? && user.valid_password?(params[:password])
```

instead of supplying password verification in a block:

```
if user.valid_for_authentication? { user.valid_password?(params[:password]) }
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem. But I solved by these step

1. run **rails g migration add_lockable_to_devise**
2. add following code in db/migrate/***********_add_lockable_to_devise

   ```
   def up
    add_column :users, :failed_attempts, :integer
    add_column :users, :unlock_token, :string
    add_column :users, :locked_at, :datetime

    add_index :users, :unlock_token, unique: true

    execute("UPDATE users SET confirmed_at = NOW()")
   end

   def down
     remove_columns :users, :failed_attempts, :unlock_token, :locked_at  
   end
   ```

3.After that run **rake db:migrate**

Don't forget step 3

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and I recreated table with this migration.

Try this:

```
change_table(:admins) do |t|
  t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave for your answer.
I did the same as you have suggested, but got the error - undefined method `lockable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Table:0x9a4bd80>

Comment: the issue, may be migration file  having column names instead of devise method names. check once.

Comment: it seems admins table is not present. did u dropped it...if so , recreate the table and run above code in migration file.

Comment: Re-created the table.
Migration script for above is -
*
  def change
 change_table(:admins) do |t|
   t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both
 end
  end *

Comment: nop, while executing **rake db:migrate** for above script I got **undefined method 'lockable'** error

Comment: try -- Do 'rails g devise:install' instead of 'rails g devise install' then migrate db then it should work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51430/discussion-between-deepu-and-dave)

Comment: In migration You'll also want to add an index on the unlock_token if :email or :both. add_index :users, :unlock_token, :unique => true

Comment: it seems you have migration issue, check if lockable is associated with admin, the above code should work

Comment: `t.lockable` was available in older versions of `Devise` and is not available in `Devise v 3.2.4` which is why OP is getting error as `undefined method `lockable' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Table:0x9a4bd80>` using your answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is a tricky case, and I can't help you much but can guide you to help yourself.

Devise updates the failed_attempts count at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/lockable.rb line number 92.

```
def valid_for_authentication?
    return super unless persisted? && lock_strategy_enabled?(:failed_attempts)

    # Unlock the user if the lock is expired, no matter
    # if the user can login or not (wrong password, etc)
    unlock_access! if lock_expired?

    if super && !access_locked?
      true
    else
      self.failed_attempts ||= 0
      self.failed_attempts += 1
      if attempts_exceeded?
        lock_access! unless access_locked?
      else
        save(validate: false)
      end
      false
    end
  end
```

You have to edit the installed gem's corresponding file and add a logger or do puts to stdout to see if the else loop gets executed. The only possible reason why it won't be is when the first line return gets called.

I dont think you can solve this without digging deep into devise code since your configurations are correct.