# How can I update table when a user is locked after maximum login attempts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

In my rails application, I managed to lock users after a maximum failed login treshold using Devise lockable, but how can I update the table so that I can add an entry to user denoting this user is locked also with timestamp !

I just don't know where to put that code in !

I tried to create a file called "lockable.rb" in Initializer with following code,

```
    def lock_access!(opts = { })
      @user.is_lock = "Yes"
      @user.reason_of_deactivation = "Failed login attempt"
      @user.deactivated_date = DateTime.now
      @user.save
    end
```

That didn't worked out !

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Comment: The question has already been:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184514/how-to-lock-users-using-devise

Comment: @Pavan: No, I haven't, that method is not executing.

Comment: @RuslanKornienko: No, that's a different question O.o

Comment: A conditional callback maybe?

Comment: @bsvin33t: Would you be kind enough to elaborate ? like which conditional callback ! I'm not a pro on ror !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 1 hour of research and testing I myself found solution, I overrided lockable.rb in Devise gem and added code.

Created file lockable.rb in lib/devise/models/lockable.rb

```
    def lock_access!(opts = { })
      super
      self.is_lock = "Yes"
      self.reason_of_deactivation = "Exceeded max login threshold"
      self.deactivated_date = DateTime.now
    end
```

Closed.

Answer (score 1):

One potential solution I see here is that you could have  a condition inside a callback on `after_save` where, you check if the user is locked.

If the User is locked, update the timestamp with the `current time` or `updated_at` .

This solution might have problems as the callback would get executed every time a save is called on the user object, thus updating the timestamp. Please take care to add enough conditions to prevent this from happening.

Also, please write tests around this, so that at some later point of time, when you revisit that part of code, it will provide you with some context about the conditions.